# Password change notification problem exclude OU powershell

Tags: powershell

We are using a good script that we would like to extend to search for users everywhere except one OU. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance for your help!

[PasswordChangeNotification](https://github.com/titlerequired/public/blob/master/PasswordChangeNotification.ps1)

How to instert this code?

```
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -filter * -SearchBase 'OU=test,DC=test,DC=com' | foreach {

    if($_.distinguishedname -ne "OU=not,OU=that,OU=orgUnit,OU=test,DC=test,DC=com"){

        $users=Get-ADUser -filter * -searchbase $_.distinguishedname -ResultPageSize 2000 -resultSetSize 500 -searchscope Onelevel | where-object enabled -eq true 
        $total=($users | measure-object).count
        New-Object psobject -Property @{
            OU=$_.Name;
            A=$Total
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to insert this snippet into that github link, you should talk with the owner instead. Aslo, your condition can be reduced to `Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -LDAPFilter "(!distinguishedName=OU-to-exclude..)" -SearchBase ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On [line 132 of the file you've linked to](https://github.com/titlerequired/public/blob/c3d3f379b4beb14456b37d93e5403c99095ddefd/PasswordChangeNotification.ps1#L132), you'll find the statement that actually queries Active Directory for the users:

```
$users = get-aduser -filter {(Enabled -eq $true) -and (PasswordNeverExpires -eq $false)} -properties Name, PasswordNeverExpires, PasswordExpired, PasswordLastSet, EmailAddress | where { $_.passwordexpired -eq $false }
```

Add the following statement to the next line:

```
$users = $users |Where-Object distinguishedname -notlike "*,OU=not,OU=that,OU=orgUnit,OU=test,DC=test,DC=com"
```

... and leave the rest of the script as-is